# angular-ui-router 0.2.7 nothing showing on page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need help. I build web app with angularjs 1.2.5 and angular-ui-router. When I use angular-ui-router v0.2.0 all works fine. But when I have upgraded angular-ui-router to v0.2.5 or v0.2.7 I see empty page. At chrome DevTools console I see that all templates run but nothing showing on page. And are no errors in DevTools console.

Comment: You'll need to show us some code to get any help.  Can you provide an example of the problem with a plunkr?

Comment: I have tried but I use html5 and base url. And I can't use html5 at Plunker. Without html5 plunkr works fine with angular-ui-router v0.2.7 http://plnkr.co/edit/k5ZEA6gU90i3zARsVDot?p=preview

Comment: I've downloaded and executed this locally (with and without html5mode enabled) and it seems to work for me (sorry! :)).  Perhaps you could populate a github repo with a toy app which demonstrates the breakage?

Comment: I have the same problem in my project. Disabling html5 mode makes no difference in my project. I will let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same experience moving from v0.2.0 to v0.2.7. Removing `ng-cloak` from the `ui-view` element was the solution in my case.

I changed

```
<div ui-view="page-wrapper" class="ng-cloak" ng-cloak></div>
```

to

```
<div ui-view="page-wrapper"></div>
```

I moved `ng-cloak` to the template.